# How to transfer multiple files using c#?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, file-transfer

I want to transfer folder from client to server. I found the code on this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24017/File-Transfer-using-Socket-Application-in-C-NET-2) to transfer file and its working fine.

But i want to transfer multiple files and there is an error as only 1 files is transferred. I modified the code and used FolderBrowseDialogue instead of OpenFileDialogue. I have used following code to transfer file.

```
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
{
    FTClientCode.SendFile(f);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem was at serverside when **backgroundWorker1** was calling **StartServer()**, so server was started only once and this function was never called again, So i wrote **StartServer()** at the end of **StartServer()** function so after getting file it server starts again and waits for next file to be received. This is not good as a function is calling itself again and again and there is no end point. But my requirement was only to receive files and do nothing else so that is why I used it.